# Automatically generate 'attr_reader' for symbols

Tags: ruby

I have the following code where I set `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` manually.

```
class Pairs
  attr_reader :pair, :asks, :bids, :isFrozen, :seq, :main_currency, :sub_currency
  attr_writer :pair, :asks, :bids, :isFrozen, :seq

  def initialize (key, args)
    @pair = key
    @main_currency, @sub_currency = key.split('_')
    args.each {|k,v| 
      if numeric?(v) then v=v.to_f end
      self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}".to_sym, v)
    }
  end

  private

  def numeric?(string)
    Float(string) != nil rescue false
  end
end
```

Is there a way to automatically set them based on the keys of the arguments, like I'm automatically filling `@k` with `v`? Can I set `attr_reader` for each `@k`?

I suppose something like:

```
self.attr_reader("@#{k}")
```

or even better for all objects of the class, something like:

```
Pairs << attr_reader("@#{k}")
```

Comment: What is `attr_write`?

Comment: Sorry, ´attr_writer´

Comment: How do you use `Pairs` with `initialize`?

Comment: random_pair = Pairs.new(key, arguments)

Comment: @bleedr That's not an answer to the question. What is `key`? What is `arguments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you may be creating this with many `keys` specific to different `Hash` if this is the case then rather than clutter the individual instances with unneeded readers for non existent keys let's use the `singleton_class` for this.

So your final `Pairs` class could look something like

```
class Pairs
  attr_reader :main_currency, :sub_currency
  attr_accessor :pair, :asks, :bids, :isFrozen, :seq

  def initialize (key, args)
    @pair = key
    @main_currency, @sub_currency = key.split('_')
    args.each do |k,v| 
      singleton_class.send(:attr_reader,k)
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", convert_numeric(v))
    end
    # Alternatively:
    # args.each do |k,v| 
    #   val = convert_numeric(v)
    #   define_singleton_method(k) {val}
    # end
  end

  private

    def convert_numeric(val)
      Float(Rational(val)) rescue val
    end
end
```

**TL;DR**

For Example: (using @mudasobwa's approach)

```
class C
  def extend_self_with_reader name
    self.class.send :attr_reader, name
  end

  def initialize *keys
    keys.each(&method(:extend_self_with_reader))
  end
end
```

This causes subsequent readers to clutter the instance and bleed across instances:

```
a = C.new(:a,:b)
a.a #=> nil
b = C.new
b.a #=> nil 
c = C.new(:r) 
c.a #=> nil
c.r #=> nil
a.methods.sort - Object.methods
#=> [:a, :b, :extend_self_with_reader, :r]
a.r #=> nil (hmmmmm)
```

Instead localize these readers buy using the `singleton_class` of the instance like:

```
class C 
  def initialize *keys 
    singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, *keys)
  end
end
```

Then

```
a = C.new(:a,:b)
a.a #=> nil
b = C.new
b.a #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `a'
c = C.new(:r) 
c.a #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `a'
c.r #=> nil
a.r #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `r'
a.methods.sort - Object.methods
#=> [:a,:b] 
b.methods.sort - Object.methods
#=> []
```

Using the `singleton_class` localizes these readers to the instance of the object rather than bleeding them into the `Class` definition. If `attr_reader` is not a requirement then this would also be sufficient:

```
keys.each {|k| define_singleton_method(k) {}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt I understood the question, but from what I get you want to dynamically extend your class with attribute readers at runtime.

This method would do:

```
def extend_self_with_reader name
  self.class.send :attr_reader, name
end
```

Test:

```
class C
  def extend_self_with_reader name
    self.class.send :attr_reader, name
  end

  def initialize *keys
    puts keys.inspect
    keys.each(&method(:extend_self_with_reader))
  end
end
cc = C.new(*%i|a b c|)
cc.a #⇒ nil
```

Comment: yes, that was the aim. Need to try to implement and check if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into `define_method`.

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the problem, but check this out:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

hash.keys.each do |key|
  define_method(key) do
    hash[key]
  end
end
```

There are now methods for a, b, and c:

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
```

That essentially makes an `attr_reader` for all the keys in the hash.  You could do something similar for an `attr_writer`.